# How can I use month.abb and stop months from being alphabetical?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this dataframe, in which I am trying to properly order the months. As you know, if I plot this, I will get alphabetical, which I don't want.

```
months  frequency   regions
April   4   Arizona
August  129 Arizona
December    43  Arizona
February    71  Arizona
January 89  Arizona
July    93  Arizona
June    11  Arizona
March   37  Arizona
May 6   Arizona
November    14  Arizona
October 28  Arizona
September   63  Arizona
```

So I use this code to convert the levels to short form which also makes ggplot in the month order desired. However, I am getting all NAs in the month as output. What is the problem?

```
df$months<-factor(df$months, levels=month.abb)


months  frequency   regions
NA  4   Arizona
NA  129 Arizona
NA  43  Arizona
NA  71  Arizona
NA  89  Arizona
NA  93  Arizona
NA  11  Arizona
NA  37  Arizona
May 6   Arizona
NA  14  Arizona
NA  28  Arizona
NA  63  Arizona
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The levels of a factor must match the observed values. If you want to change how those values print out, you need to change the labels. Try

```
df$months <- factor(df$months, levels=month.name, labels=month.abb)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `ggplot`, you could use `reorder` to get the data in the `month order`.  For example,

```
 library(ggplot2)
 ggplot(df, aes(reorder(substr(months,1,3), match(months, month.name)),
              frequency, fill=regions))+
              geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge")+
              xlab("months")+
              theme_bw()
```

[image]

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(months = c("April", "August", "December", "February", 
"January", "July", "June", "March", "May", "November", "October", 
"September", "November", "October", "September"), frequency = c(4, 
129, 43, 71, 89, 93, 11, 37, 6, 4, 18, 25, 14, 28, 63), regions = c("Arizona", 
"Arizona", "Arizona", "Arizona", "Arizona", "Arizona", "Arizona", 
"Arizona", "Arizona", "Texas", "Texas", "Texas", "Arizona", "Arizona", 
"Arizona")), .Names = c("months", "frequency", "regions"), row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "101", 
"111", "121"), class = "data.frame")
```